# Android Animate Menu Items when showing/hiding them

Tags: android, android-animation

it is possible to animate menu items when they appear in action bar ?

I have 3 fragments in an horizontal pager view, when i'm on the first, i have this :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/UuI48.png

and on the second fragment, i have this :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hZJG3.png

But when i'm swiping to one another, items in action bar just appear (pop) or disapear, and i think it would be a better user experience if they would slide like right to left.

Thanks alot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can animate your menu item in `onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)`. A poor implementation could be like this:

```
public class YourFragment extends Fragment{

private boolean mShouldAnimateMenuItem = true;


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(final Menu menu) {


    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.your_menu, menu);

    if (mShouldAnimateMenuItem){
        ImageView image = new ImageView(this);      
        image.setImageResource(R.drawable.your_menu_item_icon);
        menu.getItem(0).setActionView(image); //item in the 0 position
        Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(),R.anim.translate_from_right_to_current_accelerate_fast);
        anim.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                menu.getItem(0).setActionView(null);

            }
        });
        menu.getItem(0).getActionView().startAnimation(anim);
        mShouldAnimateMenuItem = false;

    }


    return true;
}
}
```

This way you animate the `actionView`and once you're done, you just discard the `actionView` for your item.

**translate_from_right_to_current_accelerate_fast.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fillAfter="false"
android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator" >

<translate
    android:duration="2000"
    android:fromXDelta="100%p"
    android:toXDelta="0" />

</set>
```

Comment: Is this way of doing the only one ? I worked around with it and find it a bit sloppy :/ Thanks for your fast answer btw.

Comment: No, you could retain your menu instance in `onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)` and animate whenever and wherever you want later. You can use other kinds of animations too, but remember: you have to animate a view, that's why you need to set the `actionView` for the menu item.